# Web scraping url not changing while search

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to webscrape https://in.udacity.com/courses/all. I need to get the courses shown while entering the search query. For eg: if I enter python, there are 17 courses coming as results.I need to fetch those courses only. Here the search query is not passed as part of the url.(not get method).so the html content is also not changing. Then how can I fetch those results without going through the entire course list.
in this code i am fetching all the course links getting the content of it and seraching the search term in that content.but it is not giving me the result that i expect.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Comment
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

def tag_visible(element):
    if element.parent.name in ['style', 'script', 'head', 'title', 'meta', '[document]']:
        return False
    if isinstance(element, Comment):
        return False
    return True


def text_from_html(body):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(body, 'html.parser')
    texts = soup.findAll(text=True)
    visible_texts = filter(tag_visible, texts)  
    return u" ".join(t.strip() for t in visible_texts)

page = requests.get("https://in.udacity.com/courses/all")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
courses = soup.select('a.capitalize')

search_term = input("enter the course:")
for link in courses:
    #print("https://in.udacity.com" + link['href'])
    html = urllib.request.urlopen("https://in.udacity.com" + link['href']).read()

    if search_term in text_from_html(html).lower():
        print('\n'+link.text)
        print("https://in.udacity.com" + link['href'])
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: @Merin why did you untick my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) and [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://in.udacity.com/courses/all")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
courses = soup.find_all("a", class_="capitalize")

for course in courses:
    print(course.text)
```

OUTPUT:

```
VR Foundations
VR Mobile 360
VR High-Immersion
Google Analytics
Artificial Intelligence for Trading
Python Foundation
.
.
.
```

EDIT:

As explainged by @Martin Evans, the Ajax call behind the search is not doing what you think it is, it is probably keeping the count of the search i.e. *how many users searched for AI* It basically is filtering out the search based on the keyword in the `search_term`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

page = requests.get("https://in.udacity.com/courses/all")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
courses = soup.find_all("a", class_="capitalize")
search_term = "AI"

for course in courses:
    if re.search(search_term, course.text, re.IGNORECASE):
        print(course.text)
```

OUTPUT:

```
AI Programming with Python
Blockchain Developer Nanodegree program
Knowledge-Based AI: Cognitive Systems
```

Comment: @Merin why did you untick my answer?

Comment: i tried the method you suggested.(by filtering out all the courses which contain the search term).but it is giving me more courses than that are listed in the webpage.for eg when i search for python 17 courses are coming in the webpage.but when i am filtering out.more than 17 are coming.

Answer (score 1):

The udacity page is actually returning all available courses when you request it. When you enter a search, the page is simply filtering the available data. This is why you do not see any changes to the URL when entering a search. A check using the browser's developer tools also confirms this. It also explains why the "search" is so fast.

As such, if you are searching for a given course, you would just need to filter the results yourself. For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req = requests.get("https://in.udacity.com/courses/all")
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")
a_tags = soup.find_all("a", class_="capitalize")

print("Number of courses:", len(a_tags))
print()

for a_tag in a_tags:
    course = a_tag.text

    if "python" in course.lower():
        print(course)
```

This would display all courses with `Python` in the title:

```
Number of courses: 225

Python Foundation
AI Programming with Python
Programming Foundations with Python
Data Structures & Algorithms in Python
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the tutorials for how to use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) (for making HTTP requests) and [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) (for processing HTML). This will teach you what you need to know to download the pages, and extract the data from the HTML.

You will use the function [`BeautifulSoup.find_all()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) to locate all of the `<div>` elements in the page HTML, with `class=course-summary-card`. The content you want is within that `<div>`, and after reading the above links it should be trivial for you to figure out the rest ;)

Btw, one helpful tool for you as you learn how to do this will be to use the "Inspect element" feature (for Chrome/Firefox), which can be accessed by right clicking on elements in the browser, that enables you to look at the source code surrounding the element you're interested in extracting, so you can get information like it's class or id, parent divs, etc that will allow you to select it in BeautifulSoup/lxml/etc.

Comment: I think there should be a better option other than beautiful soup and requests to extract the search results

Comment: I think if you read more about web scraping, you'll find that this is probably the simplest solution to your problem. You might wish that there were something easier, but this is about as easy as it gets for writing scripts to fetch HTML and extract text from it.