# Scraping results from booking flow with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to scrape the results of the booking search for [Gestur website](http://www.gestour.eu/) using python and BeautifulSoup. As I fill in the minimum required fields and submit the results, the URL doesn't change and looking at the Network tab I can't see any data downloaded that I could easily retrieve.

Is there anyway to scrape the results?

Comment: Possibly a dupe of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54625693/web-scraping-url-not-changing-while-search/54625750#54625750

Comment: The question is similar but the page content/behaviour is different.

Answer (score 0):

The site in question seems to achieve its functionality by including the content of URL `http://gestour.nefesy.com/b2c/b2c.php` in an iFrame. That page has a lot of scripting in it. You may need to analyse the scripting to determine how to intercept the submitted data. But it's most likely the page you need to interact with, and fortunately it doesn't appear to be scripted to redirect to the framed page if it isn't embedded.